# Is this question really off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, off-topic, reopen-closed

[I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13707746/118153) about how my code can interface with Quicktime - a formerly popular solution for browser audio, I felt that it was relevant to a wider audience than myself, and it should have a specific answer. It is also a very real problem which I need to solve asap.

I recognize that frequently the precise skill combination required to answer such a question is uncommon - which is most of the reason that I put it on Stack Overflow.

When I do solve such odd questions, I have a policy of posting my solution as an answer (and if another answer which I could not accept is more generalized, accepting it instead), thereby search-indexing the answer for the next person with the issue.

Why was this particular question on Stack Overflow closed as "Off Topic"?

Comment: Had you flagged the question with a custom explanation, I might have summarily reopened it, as I too don't see how this is off-topic.  However, since you've asked for community input, I'll wait and see what the community has to say. ;)

Comment: Note that comments you place on your own post will go unanswered unless you preface them with @user; nobody is listening.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: I have to say it took me some reading to discover the programming question there. The particular format is somewhat confusing. "Ah, that's his problem. What, he has a solution already? What's this alternative business? Hmm, seems like a Super User question...ah no, wait a minute"

Comment: it is a poorly presented question though.  The requirements aren't very clear, and you don't get to the point quick enough

Comment: I'll avoid using an expository format in the future then - thank you for the feedback, @Bart and Sam-I-am.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you for clarifying a better course of action. I'll use flags if I should have similar (hopefully valid) concerns.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Link to the link to the main FAQ is helpful, had never heard of it before. Will now read entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like an on-topic question to me.  I've gone ahead and reopened it.